# Converting json to array with recursive method?

Tags: php, recursion, php-5.3, json

I am trying to convert json string inside an array into array,

```
$config = array(
    "type"  => '{"category":"admin","page":"page"}',
    "say"     => "Hello",
    "php"   => array(
        "say"     => "no",
        "type"  => '{"category":"admin","page":"page"}',
        "gran"  =>array(
            "name" => "Hi"
        )
    )
);
```

My working code,

```
class objectify
{

    public function json_to_array($array, $recursive = true)
    {
        # if $array is not an array, let's make it array with one value of former $array.
        if (!is_array($array)) $array = array($array);

        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if($recursive === false) $array[$key] = (!empty($value) && is_string($value) && json_decode($value) != NULL) ? json_decode($value, true): $value;
                else $array[$key] = (!empty($value) && is_string($value) && json_decode($value) != NULL) ? json_decode($value, true): is_array($value) ? self::json_to_array($array) : $value;
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

It works fine *without* **recursive method** but breaks when I want to do the **recursive** as you can see in my code above,

```
$object = new objectify();
$config = $object->json_to_array($config);
print_r($config);
```

error message,

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2048 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\test\2012\php\set_variable.php on line 79
```

I just want to get this result,

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
            [category] => admin
            [page] => page
        )
    [say] => Hello
        (
            [say] => no
            [type] => {"category":"admin","page":"page"}
            [gran] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Hi
                )

        )

)
```

**EDIT:**

```
$config = 'type={"category":"admin","page":"page"}&text_editor={"name":"mce-basic"}&parent_id=self&subtitle=true&description=true&content_1=true&script_1=true&primary_image=true';
parse_str($config,$array);
print_r($array);
```

result,

```
Array
(
    [type] => {"category":"admin","page":"page"}
    [text_editor] => {"name":"mce-basic"}
    [parent_id] => self
    [subtitle] => true
    [description] => true
    [content_1] => true
    [script_1] => true
    [primary_image] => true
)
```

Comment: Might I inquire as to exactly why you've got partially (and only partially) parsed JSON in your data structure?

Comment: How did you get an array of JSON strings in the first place?  Seems like those should have come in as a JSON array that you could just decode all at once.

Comment: Do you need help addressing the memory issue?

Comment: @MarkReed - please see my edit above.

Comment: OK... still don't know why you're passing in query parameters with JSON values instead of just putting a JSON document in the request body.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you seem to be mixing static and non-static: You generate an object to be able to call your function, but in the function itself you treat it as static in the recursive section `self::....`. You might as well declare it static and call it static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
$full_array = array_map('json_decode', $array);
```

If not all your parameters are JSON, and you want actual arrays instead of `stdClass` objects, you may have to do this:

```
function json_decode_array($input) { 
  $from_json =  json_decode($input, true);  
  return $from_json ? $from_json : $input; 
}
$full_array = array_map('json_decode_array', $array);
```

If you have more levels of nested arrays outside of the JSON, then you have to do your own recursion.  Try this version of objectify:

```
class objectify
{
  public function json_mapper($value, $recursive = true) {
    if (!empty($value) && is_string($value) &&
        $decoded = json_decode($value, true)) {
      return $decoded;
    } elseif (is_array($value) && $recursive) {
      return array_map('objectify::json_mapper', $value);
    } else {
      return $value;
    }
  }

  // currying, anyone?
  public function json_mapper_norecurse($value) { 
     return objectify::json_mapper($value, false);
  }

  public function json_to_array($array, $recursive = true)
  {
    # if $array is not an array, let's make it array with one value of
    # former $array.
    if (!is_array($array)) {
      $array = array($array);
    }

    return array_map(
      $recursive ? 'objectify::json_mapper' 
                 : 'objectify::json_mapper_norecurse', $array);
  }
}
```

Which works fine for me on both of your sets of sample data.

Comment: These do not work Mark, I just ran both. The JSON string values are converted to empty strings.

Comment: Hm.  My result was missing the non-JSON values - fixed in edit above - but otherwise looks right.  What's different?

Comment: Looks good, did not know json_decode was recursive :) Def. the better solution op.

Comment: @MarkReed - thanks it works fine but still breaks with the array such as in my OP. I get this error `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\test\...`

Comment: @MarkReed - thanks for the edit. I am sorry to tell you that I get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_mapper() in C:\wamp\www\.. on line 109` which refers to `return json_mapper($value, false);`. But I get the result I am after...

Comment: sorry, forgot to qualify function name.  seems like you could skip that from other functions within the class...

Answer (score 2):

As far as your code is concerned, it seems you have made a mistake causing it to loop forever (last part of the recursive section):

```
is_array($value) ? self::json_to_array($array) : $value;
```

You are feeding the whole array to the recursive function instead of the value that tested to be an array.

Changing it to:

```
is_array($value) ? self::json_to_array($value) : $value;
```

Should solve that.

**Edit:** It seems that the nested ternary condition is causing the problem, if you put braces around the second one, it works:

```
        else
        {
           $array[$key] = (!empty($value) && is_string($value) && json_decode($value) != NULL)
                               ? json_decode($value, true)
                               : (is_array($value) ? self::json_to_array($value) : $value);
        }
```

[See the working example](http://codepad.org/ioq5rgB2).

Comment: thanks but still the same error `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\test\2012\php\set_variable.php on line 79`

Comment: Use PHP's built-in functions rather than your own recursion, they are far more performant.

Comment: @lauthiamkok I can't find the source, but I read somewhere that nested ternary operators can cause unexpected results. Does it change anything if you put brackets around that last section (the one I posted)?

Comment: I didn't think it was helpful encouraging a poor/misguided approach to the solution.

Comment: @lauthiamkok It seems the nested ternary was the problem, see my edit.

Comment: @PorridgeBear Good luck downvoting everybody who uses the original `mysql_` functions ;-)

Comment: Well, i'm new to this and didn't find it helpful in the grand scheme of things, though if the op insists on using his own recursion and needs help with it, what can you do. I've removed the vote.

Comment: @PorridgeBear No need to and if you can make your answer work with the OP's class it deserves to be above mine; I was just focussed on finding the problem and surprised at the downvote when finding it (the problem...). Just saying that you're going to find looooooots of misguided approaches here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert all json recursively you need to put the second param of json_decode to true

```
$config_array = json_decode($config, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done much more easily.

```
function objectify(& $v, $k) {
    $v_decoded = json_decode($v, true);
    if ($v_decoded) { $v = $v_decoded; }
}

array_walk_recursive($config, 'objectify');
print_r($config);

Array
(
[type] => Array
    (
        [category] => admin
        [page] => page
    )

[say] => Hello
[php] => Array
    (
        [say] => no
        [type] => Array
            (
                [category] => admin
                [page] => page
            )

        [gran] => Array
            (
                [name] => Hi
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: You don't need to write your own recursion, though;  json_decode is already recursive.  So once you get to the JSON, you're good.

Comment: @Porridge - thanks it works perfectly. but how can I apply `array_walk_recursive($config, 'objectify');` in a class such as the one in my OP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel framework and post parameters contain arrays, Use json_decode in array map to decode recursive values.

```
            $params = array_map('json_decode', $request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function jsonDecodeRecursively(Array &$arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $key => &$val)
    {
        if(is_string($val) && json_decode($val))
        {
            $val = json_decode($val, true);
        }

        if(is_iterable($val))
        {
            jsonDecodeRecursively($val);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

This will loop thru the parent array and decode all its sub elements json encoded arrays recusively.

Answer (score 0):

To recursively convert json strings to arrays or objects, use the following function which modifies the input array/object by reference, replaces json strings in-place, then finally returns the entire mutated payload.

From PHP8.3, `json_validate()` makes it easy to determine whether a string is valid json or not.  This native function only accepts a string as its first parameter.

My function is designed to dynamically accommodate calls which desire json strings to become objects or arrays based on the second parameter.  The default to convert json strings to arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/t5jeB))

```
function decode_json_only(array|object &$data, bool $toArray = true)
{
     foreach ($data as &$v) {
        if (is_string($v) && json_validate($v)) {
            $v = json_decode($v, $toArray);
        }
        if (is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
            $v = (__FUNCTION__)($v, $toArray);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

var_export(decode_json_only($config));
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use the easy function:

```php
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Found here: https://gist.github.com/victorbstan/744478

```js
setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
```