# how to read all values from json object using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

**Here is my json data:**

```
      {
      "resourceType": "Patient",
      "birthDate": "1985-08-01T00:00:00Z",
      "active": true,
      "gender": "male",
      "deceasedBoolean": false,
      "id": "Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
      "careProvider": [
        {
          "display": "Physician Family Medicine",
          "reference": "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Practitioner/T3Mz3KLBDVXXgaRoee3EKAAB"
        }
      ],
      "name": [
        {
          "use": "usual",
          "family": [
            "Argonaut"
          ],
          "given": [
            "Jason"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "identifier": [
        {
          "use": "usual",
          "system": "urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.327.1.7.5.737384.0",
          "value": "E3826"
        },
        {
          "use": "usual",
          "system": "urn:oid:1.2.3.4",
          "value": "203579"
        }
      ],
      "address": [
        {
          "use": "home",
          "line": [
            "1979 Milky Way Dr."
          ],
          "city": "Verona",
          "state": "WI",
          "postalCode": "53593",
          "country": "US"
        }
      ],
      "telecom": [
        {
          "system": "phone",
          "value": "608-271-9000",
          "use": "home"
        },
        {
          "system": "phone",
          "value": "608-771-9000",
          "use": "work"
        },
        {
          "system": "email",
          "value": "open@epic.com"
        }
      ],
      "maritalStatus": {
        "text": "Married"
      },
      "communication": [
        {
          "preferred": true,
          "language": {
            "text": "English",
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.99",
                "code": "en",
                "display": "English"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "extension": [
        {
          "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-race",
          "valueCodeableConcept": {
            "text": "Asian",
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "2.16.840.1.113883.5.104",
                "code": "2028-9",
                "display": "Asian"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity",
          "valueCodeableConcept": {
            "text": "Not Hispanic or Latino",
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "2.16.840.1.113883.5.50",
                "code": "2186-5",
                "display": "Not Hispanic or Latino"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: $json = '{.....}';
$obj= json_decode($json,true);
for($i=0; $i<count($obj['extension']); $i++) {
   echo $obj['extension'][$i]["url"]. " <br /> ";
 }


but unable to read inner loop for valueCodeableConcept, please suggest me how to read json inner key & values

Answer (score 2):

use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). It returns a PHP object from a well-formed JSON string

Assuming the string in your question is stored under a variable called `$json_str`, the decoding should go something like this

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
```

You may then access it like so

```
$json_obj->resourceType; // "Patient"
```

Comment: $json = '{.....}';
$obj= json_decode($json,true);
for($i=0; $i<count($obj['extension']); $i++) {
   echo $obj['extension'][$i]["url"]. " <br /> ";
 }


but unable to read inner loop for valueCodeableConcept, please suggest me how to read json inner key & values

Answer (score 2):

> [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) - Decodes a JSON string

Example:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Comment: please check my above json object and suggest me  how to read nested json objects.for example in the above json object how to read communication key and its inner values (language and its inner loop ( coding key))

Comment: @satishkumar check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457883/converting-json-to-array-with-recursive-method

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP JSON library: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
$obj= json_decode($json,true);
if(!empty($obj->extension))
{
    foreach($obj->extension as $extension)
    {
         echo  $extension->url;
       // similarly others
     }
}
```