# Get the value of Resultcode from a decoded json array

Tags: php, json

Hi guys i know this could be easy but i have tried and still come up short. I want to get the value of the result code but still not able to print it so i can do an if statement

```
//loop through json array 

$str = file_get_contents('Response.json');
$array = json_decode($str, true);

$last = array_pop($array);

echo "<pre>";
echo $last[0];

//echo $last[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode'];
```

The line echo $last[0] works and gives me

```
{"Body":{"stkCallback":{"MerchantRequestID":"16421-6174532-2","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_DMZ_99605283_17102018133825256","ResultCode":1036,"ResultDesc":"[STK_CB - ]SMSC ACK timeout."}}}
```

But

```
$last[0]['Body']['stkCallback]['ResultCode']
```

doesn't echo or print out anything just a {

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to decode it again. Is your Response.json contents double encoded? Can you share the contents of that file?

Comment: I you can `echo` out the `$last[0]` value and you see a string, that means you have encoded json inside your json. So you would need to decode that as well. If you generate the file as well, I would recommend getting rid of the double encoding and only encode the end-result once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because that you are still getting a json from this line. You need to decode it as well:

```
print_r(json_decode($last[0],true));
```

This should return you the array you need.

Remember that the fact that you can `echo` it means that it is still in json format otherwise you would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you echo `$last[0]` you are seeing another json string, not an object. You will need to decode that too:

```
$last = json_decode(array_pop($array), true);
print_r($last);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some of your array value exists json string,
if so, this may be a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457883/converting-json-to-array-with-recursive-method)