# Unescaping a string meant to be JSON nested in JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, backslash

My server receives JSON data from a real-world device, which is then saved in a MySQL JSON field. Unfortunately, the manufacturer seems to have a bug in their code which causes part of the data to be stringified escaped JSON.

```
[
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "info",
  {
    "data": "{\"parts\":[{\"id\":1,\"serial\":\"19777\",\"type\":\"NONE\",\"key\":\"\"}]}",
    "vendor": "Test",
    "message": "Hello world"
  }
]
```

Running `json_decode` even with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` results in a string

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => info
    [3] => Array
        (
            [data] => {"parts":[{"id":1,"serial":"19777","type":"NONE","key":""}]}
            [vendor] => Test
            [message] => Hello world
        )

)
```

But the expected output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => info
    [3] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [parts] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [serial] => 19777
                                    [type] => NONE
                                    [key] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [vendor] => Test
            [message] => Hellow world
        )

)
```

Since I cannot expect them to release a firmware update any time soon, is there any function I can run on the entire JSON to identify stringified JSON and re-encode the request before saving to MySQL, but not effect other messages that do not have a similar bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: turn any nested json data inside `$json` into associative array:

Recurse through array `$arr` using function `recurse()`, to find any elements with json data and `json_decode()` them to arrive at your expected output:

```
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
recurse($arr); // json_decode() any json inside $arr

function recurse(array &$arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recurse($value);
        } else {
            if (is_object(json_decode($value))) {
                $value = json_decode($value, true); // turn json into assoc array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/DIUKt)

Comment: The problem with this is that not every record has a `data` field. I could check with `isset`, but then I would also need to identify whether or not the string includes `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

If the primary concern is the "data" field this should work.

```
$json = '[
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "info",
  {
    "data": "{\"parts\":[{\"id\":1,\"serial\":\"19777\",\"type\":\"NONE\",\"key\":\"\"}]}",
    "vendor": "Test",
    "message": "Hello world"
  },
  {
    "data": {"parts":[{"id":1,"serial":"19777","type":"NONE","key":""}]},
    "vendor": "Test",
    "message": "Hello world"
  }
  ]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $a)
{
    if(is_array($a))
    {
        if(!is_array($a['data']))
        {
            $a['data'] = json_decode($a['data'], true);
        }
    }
    $out [] = $a;
}

print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
$full_array = array_map('json_decode', $array);
```

If not all your parameters are JSON, and you want actual arrays instead of stdClass objects, you may have to do this:

```
function json_decode_array($input) { 
  $from_json =  json_decode($input, true);  
  return $from_json ? $from_json : $input; 
}
$full_array = array_map('json_decode_array', $array);
```

Main answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458008/3398171

Google: php json_decode recursive